# My Bluetooth device is disconnecting when closing (killing) the Application ExternalAccessory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I am developing iOS App which connected to Bluetooth device via ExternalAccessory protocol. This is a part of MFi Program authentication.
I received error from the MFi Lab which tells that when we are closing (killing) the App it shouldn't disconnect from the device. 
But even the EADemo App (from apple) is disconnecting.
I did try to call unregisterFroLocalNotifications() method which didn't help.
When closing input,output streams it automatically kills the connection.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using background modes? In your case it would be `bluetooth-peripheral`

Comment: Yes i am using background , and in my case it's not bluetooth-peripheral but External accessory communication. but i reffer to when closing(killing) the application.

Comment: I also have the same problem on iOS 13. I can leave the app running in the background communicating no problem with the Bluetooth MFI device (External accessory) but as soon as I kill the app and restart it, the app finds the peripheral, reconnects but does not receive any response or incoming data. I also tried to close the stream, set the delegate and session to nil to no avail. It works from time to time so I suspect a race condition when closing the app not properly de-initializing. This is specific to ExternalAccessory as it works fine over WiFi. So any update?